# Don't know how to loop over grouped json in Handlebars

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have the following JSON

```
    {  
       "Marketing":[  
          {  
             "Id":"RequestTypeSet_{dc504202-b19f-49ec-a89b-fa96f84a1da0}",
             "Title":"Add a new event to the intranet",
             "Description":"Submit your event details for publishing to the events section of the intranet.",
             "Url":"",
             "PictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=22cb1d8f-7887-48dd-9b48-4a6f818c302b",
             "InstancePictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=0b260bf4-2cfb-48a0-9f05-e0c431e07fba",
             "AddUrl":"https://domainname/default.aspx?requestTypeSetId=dc504202-b19f-49ec-a89b-fa96f84a1da0&action=add",
             "DetailsUrl":"https://domainname/AppFeatures.aspx?requestTypeSetId=dc504202-b19f-49ec-a89b-fa96f84a1da0",
             "Slug":"Primary-Category-Marketing Alphabetical-A",
             "Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
             "TypeName":"RequestTypeSet",
             "TypeId":"{dc504202-b19f-49ec-a89b-fa96f84a1da0}",
             "Categories":[  
                {  
                   "TermSetId":"c00f1ae9-1fa3-4d39-92e1-3cf2bfe117f9",
                   "TermSetName":"Primary Category",
                   "TermName":"Marketing",
                   "TermInternalName":null,
                   "TermIconRef":null
                }
             ],
             "PrimaryCategoryTerm":"Marketing",
             "SecondaryCategoryTerm":"",
             "Installed":false,
             "IsNew":false,
             "IsFeatured":false,
             "IsPrivate":false,
             "RequiresApproval":false,
             "CreateUrl":"https://domainname/requestwizard.aspx?requestTypeId=2beb3d49-ca57-4876-8308-8e0c55bcd556",
             "BuildLogUrl":null,
             "Owner":null,
             "IsOwner":false,
             "ScreenshotUrl":null,
             "Verbs":[  

             ]
          },
          {  
             "Id":"RequestTypeSet_{a60f3558-77ff-4ff3-98ed-82b1bcda75d3}",
             "Title":"Add a news article to the intranet",
             "Description":"Submit your news story for publishing to the news section of the intranet.",
             "Url":"",
             "PictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=22cb1d8f-7887-48dd-9b48-4a6f818c302b",
             "InstancePictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=0b260bf4-2cfb-48a0-9f05-e0c431e07fba",
             "AddUrl":"https://domainname/default.aspx?requestTypeSetId=a60f3558-77ff-4ff3-98ed-82b1bcda75d3&action=add",
             "DetailsUrl":"https://domainname/AppFeatures.aspx?requestTypeSetId=a60f3558-77ff-4ff3-98ed-82b1bcda75d3",
             "Slug":"Primary-Category-Marketing Alphabetical-A",
             "Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
             "TypeName":"RequestTypeSet",
             "TypeId":"{a60f3558-77ff-4ff3-98ed-82b1bcda75d3}",
             "Categories":[  
                {  
                   "TermSetId":"c00f1ae9-1fa3-4d39-92e1-3cf2bfe117f9",
                   "TermSetName":"Primary Category",
                   "TermName":"Marketing",
                   "TermInternalName":null,
                   "TermIconRef":null
                }
             ],
             "PrimaryCategoryTerm":"Marketing",
             "SecondaryCategoryTerm":"",
             "Installed":false,
             "IsNew":false,
             "IsFeatured":false,
             "IsPrivate":false,
             "RequiresApproval":false,
             "CreateUrl":"https://domainname/requestwizard.aspx?requestTypeId=8edcd4b3-0db3-4dd9-bc2e-42078ca7ebed",
             "BuildLogUrl":null,
             "Owner":null,
             "IsOwner":false,
             "ScreenshotUrl":null,
             "Verbs":[  

             ]
          },
          {  
             "Id":"RequestTypeSet_{17f46093-b3cc-4ed9-a4f4-02f8fc1bddd8}",
             "Title":"Attend a show or conference",
             "Description":"Book your place at an event.",
             "Url":"",
             "PictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=22cb1d8f-7887-48dd-9b48-4a6f818c302b",
             "InstancePictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=0b260bf4-2cfb-48a0-9f05-e0c431e07fba",
             "AddUrl":"https://domainname/default.aspx?requestTypeSetId=17f46093-b3cc-4ed9-a4f4-02f8fc1bddd8&action=add",
             "DetailsUrl":"https://domainname/AppFeatures.aspx?requestTypeSetId=17f46093-b3cc-4ed9-a4f4-02f8fc1bddd8",
             "Slug":"Primary-Category-Marketing Alphabetical-A",
             "Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
             "TypeName":"RequestTypeSet",
             "TypeId":"{17f46093-b3cc-4ed9-a4f4-02f8fc1bddd8}",
             "Categories":[  
                {  
                   "TermSetId":"c00f1ae9-1fa3-4d39-92e1-3cf2bfe117f9",
                   "TermSetName":"Primary Category",
                   "TermName":"Marketing",
                   "TermInternalName":null,
                   "TermIconRef":null
                }
             ],
             "PrimaryCategoryTerm":"Marketing",
             "SecondaryCategoryTerm":"",
             "Installed":false,
             "IsNew":false,
             "IsFeatured":false,
             "IsPrivate":false,
             "RequiresApproval":false,
             "CreateUrl":"https://domainname/requestwizard.aspx?requestTypeId=139ffbfc-42f9-4370-a0a5-20091d72d71f",
             "BuildLogUrl":null,
             "Owner":null,
             "IsOwner":false,
             "ScreenshotUrl":null,
             "Verbs":[  

             ]
          },
          {  
             "Id":"RequestTypeSet_{9fe6834b-2151-490c-828f-cdc54939daf0}",
             "Title":"Create a competitor file",
             "Description":"Create a competitor file using the standard template.",
             "Url":"",
             "PictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=22cb1d8f-7887-48dd-9b48-4a6f818c302b",
             "InstancePictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=0b260bf4-2cfb-48a0-9f05-e0c431e07fba",
             "AddUrl":"https://domainname/default.aspx?requestTypeSetId=9fe6834b-2151-490c-828f-cdc54939daf0&action=add",
             "DetailsUrl":"https://domainname/AppFeatures.aspx?requestTypeSetId=9fe6834b-2151-490c-828f-cdc54939daf0",
             "Slug":"Primary-Category-Marketing Alphabetical-C",
             "Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
             "TypeName":"RequestTypeSet",
             "TypeId":"{9fe6834b-2151-490c-828f-cdc54939daf0}",
             "Categories":[  
                {  
                   "TermSetId":"c00f1ae9-1fa3-4d39-92e1-3cf2bfe117f9",
                   "TermSetName":"Primary Category",
                   "TermName":"Marketing",
                   "TermInternalName":null,
                   "TermIconRef":null
                }
             ],
             "PrimaryCategoryTerm":"Marketing",
             "SecondaryCategoryTerm":"",
             "Installed":false,
             "IsNew":false,
             "IsFeatured":false,
             "IsPrivate":false,
             "RequiresApproval":false,
             "CreateUrl":"https://domainname/requestwizard.aspx?requestTypeId=b4039615-093f-43ec-ab84-387ee2588809",
             "BuildLogUrl":null,
             "Owner":null,
             "IsOwner":false,
             "ScreenshotUrl":null,
             "Verbs":[  

             ]
          },
          {  
             "Id":"RequestTypeSet_{09ef0e4a-1cca-4ff2-8b82-d05ac7c34100}",
             "Title":"Create a new brochure",
             "Description":"Create a new marketing brochure using standard templates.",
             "Url":"",
             "PictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=22cb1d8f-7887-48dd-9b48-4a6f818c302b",
             "InstancePictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=0b260bf4-2cfb-48a0-9f05-e0c431e07fba",
             "AddUrl":"https://domainname/default.aspx?requestTypeSetId=09ef0e4a-1cca-4ff2-8b82-d05ac7c34100&action=add",
             "DetailsUrl":"https://domainname/AppFeatures.aspx?requestTypeSetId=09ef0e4a-1cca-4ff2-8b82-d05ac7c34100",
             "Slug":"Primary-Category-Marketing Alphabetical-C",
             "Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
             "TypeName":"RequestTypeSet",
             "TypeId":"{09ef0e4a-1cca-4ff2-8b82-d05ac7c34100}",
             "Categories":[  
                {  
                   "TermSetId":"c00f1ae9-1fa3-4d39-92e1-3cf2bfe117f9",
                   "TermSetName":"Primary Category",
                   "TermName":"Marketing",
                   "TermInternalName":null,
                   "TermIconRef":null
                }
             ],
             "PrimaryCategoryTerm":"Marketing",
             "SecondaryCategoryTerm":"",
             "Installed":false,
             "IsNew":false,
             "IsFeatured":false,
             "IsPrivate":false,
             "RequiresApproval":false,
             "CreateUrl":"https://domainname/requestwizard.aspx?requestTypeId=4b510e2f-a222-4b84-b7ec-9589d113464b",
             "BuildLogUrl":null,
             "Owner":null,
             "IsOwner":false,
             "ScreenshotUrl":null,
             "Verbs":[  

             ]
          },
          {  
             "Id":"RequestTypeSet_{bfd1552f-5a71-40d8-8833-801350a29c3e}",
             "Title":"Create a new Marketing Project",
             "Description":"Create a project site for a marketing project.",
             "Url":"",
             "PictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=22cb1d8f-7887-48dd-9b48-4a6f818c302b",
             "InstancePictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=0b260bf4-2cfb-48a0-9f05-e0c431e07fba",
             "AddUrl":"https://domainname/default.aspx?requestTypeSetId=bfd1552f-5a71-40d8-8833-801350a29c3e&action=add",
             "DetailsUrl":"https://domainname/AppFeatures.aspx?requestTypeSetId=bfd1552f-5a71-40d8-8833-801350a29c3e",
             "Slug":"Primary-Category-Marketing Alphabetical-C",
             "Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
             "TypeName":"RequestTypeSet",
             "TypeId":"{bfd1552f-5a71-40d8-8833-801350a29c3e}",
             "Categories":[  
                {  
                   "TermSetId":"c00f1ae9-1fa3-4d39-92e1-3cf2bfe117f9",
                   "TermSetName":"Primary Category",
                   "TermName":"Marketing",
                   "TermInternalName":null,
                   "TermIconRef":null
                }
             ],
             "PrimaryCategoryTerm":"Marketing",
             "SecondaryCategoryTerm":"",
             "Installed":false,
             "IsNew":false,
             "IsFeatured":false,
             "IsPrivate":false,
             "RequiresApproval":false,
             "CreateUrl":"https://domainname/requestwizard.aspx?requestTypeId=f2d5b338-7faf-40b5-a219-f21182067417",
             "BuildLogUrl":null,
             "Owner":null,
             "IsOwner":false,
             "ScreenshotUrl":null,
             "Verbs":[  

             ]
          },
          {  
             "Id":"RequestTypeSet_{e7f7e7e2-e0f5-4421-a145-6ade2bcdfa39}",
             "Title":"Launch a new product",
             "Description":"Execute the campaign launch process for a new product.",
             "Url":"",
             "PictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=22cb1d8f-7887-48dd-9b48-4a6f818c302b",
             "InstancePictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=0b260bf4-2cfb-48a0-9f05-e0c431e07fba",
             "AddUrl":"https://domainname/default.aspx?requestTypeSetId=e7f7e7e2-e0f5-4421-a145-6ade2bcdfa39&action=add",
             "DetailsUrl":"https://domainname/AppFeatures.aspx?requestTypeSetId=e7f7e7e2-e0f5-4421-a145-6ade2bcdfa39",
             "Slug":"Primary-Category-Marketing Alphabetical-L",
             "Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
             "TypeName":"RequestTypeSet",
             "TypeId":"{e7f7e7e2-e0f5-4421-a145-6ade2bcdfa39}",
             "Categories":[  
                {  
                   "TermSetId":"c00f1ae9-1fa3-4d39-92e1-3cf2bfe117f9",
                   "TermSetName":"Primary Category",
                   "TermName":"Marketing",
                   "TermInternalName":null,
                   "TermIconRef":null
                }
             ],
             "PrimaryCategoryTerm":"Marketing",
             "SecondaryCategoryTerm":"",
             "Installed":false,
             "IsNew":false,
             "IsFeatured":false,
             "IsPrivate":false,
             "RequiresApproval":false,
             "CreateUrl":"https://domainname/requestwizard.aspx?requestTypeId=b295ef4c-e5a2-4263-b55d-bd6ce8a7fde7",
             "BuildLogUrl":null,
             "Owner":null,
             "IsOwner":false,
             "ScreenshotUrl":null,
             "Verbs":[  

             ]
          },
          {  
             "Id":"RequestTypeSet_{e981649a-4719-44dc-83e8-f32db5d0ec70}",
             "Title":"New Starter Induction Process",
             "Description":"Manage an employee induction procedure.",
             "Url":"",
             "PictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=368ef8cd-8a0f-4ff6-bcff-b27b46ccd70d",
             "InstancePictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=874c1929-debb-40da-aa2a-e73ccb6f0468",
             "AddUrl":"https://domainname/default.aspx?requestTypeSetId=e981649a-4719-44dc-83e8-f32db5d0ec70&action=add",
             "DetailsUrl":"https://domainname/AppFeatures.aspx?requestTypeSetId=e981649a-4719-44dc-83e8-f32db5d0ec70",
             "Slug":"Primary-Category-HR Primary-Category-Marketing Alphabetical-N",
             "Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
             "TypeName":"RequestTypeSet",
             "TypeId":"{e981649a-4719-44dc-83e8-f32db5d0ec70}",
             "Categories":[  
                {  
                   "TermSetId":"c00f1ae9-1fa3-4d39-92e1-3cf2bfe117f9",
                   "TermSetName":"Primary Category",
                   "TermName":"HR",
                   "TermInternalName":null,
                   "TermIconRef":null
                },
                {  
                   "TermSetId":"c00f1ae9-1fa3-4d39-92e1-3cf2bfe117f9",
                   "TermSetName":"Primary Category",
                   "TermName":"Marketing",
                   "TermInternalName":null,
                   "TermIconRef":null
                }
             ],
             "PrimaryCategoryTerm":"Marketing",
             "SecondaryCategoryTerm":"",
             "Installed":false,
             "IsNew":false,
             "IsFeatured":false,
             "IsPrivate":false,
             "RequiresApproval":false,
             "CreateUrl":"https://domainname/requestwizard.aspx?requestTypeId=c00b88c5-f1aa-4c58-8759-8dda20205c92",
             "BuildLogUrl":null,
             "Owner":null,
             "IsOwner":false,
             "ScreenshotUrl":null,
             "Verbs":[  

             ]
          }
       ],
       "Finance":[  
          {  
             "Id":"RequestTypeSet_{24fc9742-1974-4612-81d1-8de53f723fea}",
             "Title":"Business Plan",
             "Description":"Create a personal or shared business plan using the standard templates.",
             "Url":"",
             "PictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=22cb1d8f-7887-48dd-9b48-4a6f818c302b",
             "InstancePictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=0b260bf4-2cfb-48a0-9f05-e0c431e07fba",
             "AddUrl":"https://domainname/default.aspx?requestTypeSetId=24fc9742-1974-4612-81d1-8de53f723fea&action=add",
             "DetailsUrl":"https://domainname/AppFeatures.aspx?requestTypeSetId=24fc9742-1974-4612-81d1-8de53f723fea",
             "Slug":"Primary-Category-Finance Alphabetical-B",
             "Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
             "TypeName":"RequestTypeSet",
             "TypeId":"{24fc9742-1974-4612-81d1-8de53f723fea}",
             "Categories":[  
                {  
                   "TermSetId":"c00f1ae9-1fa3-4d39-92e1-3cf2bfe117f9",
                   "TermSetName":"Primary Category",
                   "TermName":"Finance",
                   "TermInternalName":null,
                   "TermIconRef":null
                }
             ],
             "PrimaryCategoryTerm":"Finance",
             "SecondaryCategoryTerm":"",
             "Installed":false,
             "IsNew":false,
             "IsFeatured":false,
             "IsPrivate":false,
             "RequiresApproval":false,
             "CreateUrl":"https://domainname/requestwizard.aspx?requestTypeId=91728e72-ae57-48af-933c-279a3cae802d",
             "BuildLogUrl":null,
             "Owner":null,
             "IsOwner":false,
             "ScreenshotUrl":null,
             "Verbs":[  

             ]
          },
          {  
             "Id":"RequestTypeSet_{63f184eb-884d-45d3-a6b6-1719816be986}",
             "Title":"Cashflow forecast",
             "Description":"Create a cashflow forecast using the standard templates",
             "Url":"",
             "PictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=22cb1d8f-7887-48dd-9b48-4a6f818c302b",
             "InstancePictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=0b260bf4-2cfb-48a0-9f05-e0c431e07fba",
             "AddUrl":"https://domainname/default.aspx?requestTypeSetId=63f184eb-884d-45d3-a6b6-1719816be986&action=add",
             "DetailsUrl":"https://domainname/AppFeatures.aspx?requestTypeSetId=63f184eb-884d-45d3-a6b6-1719816be986",
             "Slug":"Primary-Category-Finance Alphabetical-C",
             "Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
             "TypeName":"RequestTypeSet",
             "TypeId":"{63f184eb-884d-45d3-a6b6-1719816be986}",
             "Categories":[  
                {  
                   "TermSetId":"c00f1ae9-1fa3-4d39-92e1-3cf2bfe117f9",
                   "TermSetName":"Primary Category",
                   "TermName":"Finance",
                   "TermInternalName":null,
                   "TermIconRef":null
                }
             ],
             "PrimaryCategoryTerm":"Finance",
             "SecondaryCategoryTerm":"",
             "Installed":false,
             "IsNew":false,
             "IsFeatured":false,
             "IsPrivate":false,
             "RequiresApproval":false,
             "CreateUrl":"https://domainname/requestwizard.aspx?requestTypeId=5dd3a219-e130-438a-8814-6f9aa13c4bef",
             "BuildLogUrl":null,
             "Owner":null,
             "IsOwner":false,
             "ScreenshotUrl":null,
             "Verbs":[  

             ]
          },
          {  
             "Id":"RequestTypeSet_{15a42b73-6f1f-41fd-b871-66a6e50aef6b}",
             "Title":"Expenses Claim Process",
             "Description":"Manage an employee request for an expenses claim",
             "LongDescription":"",
             "Url":"",
             "PictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=22cb1d8f-7887-48dd-9b48-4a6f818c302b",
             "InstancePictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=0b260bf4-2cfb-48a0-9f05-e0c431e07fba",
             "AddUrl":"https://domainname/default.aspx?requestTypeSetId=15a42b73-6f1f-41fd-b871-66a6e50aef6b&action=add",
             "DetailsUrl":"https://domainname/AppFeatures.aspx?requestTypeSetId=15a42b73-6f1f-41fd-b871-66a6e50aef6b",
             "Slug":"Primary-Category-Finance Alphabetical-E",
             "Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
             "TypeName":"RequestTypeSet",
             "TypeId":"{15a42b73-6f1f-41fd-b871-66a6e50aef6b}",
             "Categories":[  
                {  
                   "TermSetId":"c00f1ae9-1fa3-4d39-92e1-3cf2bfe117f9",
                   "TermSetName":"Primary Category",
                   "TermName":"Finance",
                   "TermInternalName":null,
                   "TermIconRef":null
                }
             ],
             "PrimaryCategoryTerm":"Finance",
             "SecondaryCategoryTerm":"",
             "Installed":false,
             "IsNew":false,
             "IsFeatured":false,
             "IsPrivate":false,
             "RequiresApproval":false,
             "CreateUrl":"https://domainname/requestwizard.aspx?requestTypeId=d56c90b9-78a1-4c72-a6e8-0d5a77edb75c",
             "BuildLogUrl":null,
             "Owner":null,
             "IsOwner":false,
             "ScreenshotUrl":null,
             "Verbs":[  

             ]
          }
       ],
       "Admin":[  
          {  
             "Id":"RequestTypeSet_{143840a4-54e4-445d-aa1d-393777e8993a}",
             "Title":"Create a buildings or site directory",
             "Description":"Add a new directory to the intranet for locations",
             "Url":"",
             "PictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=78b0c895-9a85-4911-be80-e351a5ead2e1",
             "InstancePictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=45923135-1ed5-48bb-bd98-9a0e8d29dd6c",
             "AddUrl":"https://domainname/default.aspx?requestTypeSetId=143840a4-54e4-445d-aa1d-393777e8993a&action=add",
             "DetailsUrl":"https://domainname/AppFeatures.aspx?requestTypeSetId=143840a4-54e4-445d-aa1d-393777e8993a",
             "Slug":"Primary-Category-Admin Alphabetical-C",
             "Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
             "TypeName":"RequestTypeSet",
             "TypeId":"{143840a4-54e4-445d-aa1d-393777e8993a}",
             "Categories":[  
                {  
                   "TermSetId":"c00f1ae9-1fa3-4d39-92e1-3cf2bfe117f9",
                   "TermSetName":"Primary Category",
                   "TermName":"Admin",
                   "TermInternalName":null,
                   "TermIconRef":null
                }
             ],
             "PrimaryCategoryTerm":"Admin",
             "SecondaryCategoryTerm":"",
             "Installed":false,
             "IsNew":false,
             "IsFeatured":false,
             "IsPrivate":false,
             "RequiresApproval":false,
             "CreateUrl":"https://domainname/requestwizard.aspx?requestTypeId=b6bfa779-aed6-4ff9-843a-6ccf7ca02892",
             "BuildLogUrl":null,
             "Owner":null,
             "IsOwner":false,
             "ScreenshotUrl":null,
             "Verbs":[  

             ]
          },
          {  
             "Id":"RequestTypeSet_{bf2132a0-79c8-4679-88e5-2b1ed93621a0}",
             "Title":"Create a Health and safety site",
             "Description":"Create a health and safety portal.",
             "Url":"",
             "PictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=78b0c895-9a85-4911-be80-e351a5ead2e1",
             "InstancePictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=45923135-1ed5-48bb-bd98-9a0e8d29dd6c",
             "AddUrl":"https://domainname/default.aspx?requestTypeSetId=bf2132a0-79c8-4679-88e5-2b1ed93621a0&action=add",
             "DetailsUrl":"https://domainname/AppFeatures.aspx?requestTypeSetId=bf2132a0-79c8-4679-88e5-2b1ed93621a0",
             "Slug":"Primary-Category-Admin Alphabetical-C",
             "Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
             "TypeName":"RequestTypeSet",
             "TypeId":"{bf2132a0-79c8-4679-88e5-2b1ed93621a0}",
             "Categories":[  
                {  
                   "TermSetId":"c00f1ae9-1fa3-4d39-92e1-3cf2bfe117f9",
                   "TermSetName":"Primary Category",
                   "TermName":"Admin",
                   "TermInternalName":null,
                   "TermIconRef":null
                }
             ],
             "PrimaryCategoryTerm":"Admin",
             "SecondaryCategoryTerm":"",
             "Installed":false,
             "IsNew":false,
             "IsFeatured":false,
             "IsPrivate":false,
             "RequiresApproval":false,
             "CreateUrl":"https://domainname/requestwizard.aspx?requestTypeId=faf7f04b-3ea3-45e0-ba04-efd7e6084d7d",
             "BuildLogUrl":null,
             "Owner":null,
             "IsOwner":false,
             "ScreenshotUrl":null,
             "Verbs":[  

             ]
          },
          {  
             "Id":"RequestTypeSet_{30b5ae5a-551a-43d2-a215-b8b25b5aa627}",
             "Title":"Create a published Documents Library",
             "Description":"Enables publishing of documents to the intranet.",
             "Url":"",
             "PictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=78b0c895-9a85-4911-be80-e351a5ead2e1",
             "InstancePictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=45923135-1ed5-48bb-bd98-9a0e8d29dd6c",
             "AddUrl":"https://domainname/default.aspx?requestTypeSetId=30b5ae5a-551a-43d2-a215-b8b25b5aa627&action=add",
             "DetailsUrl":"https://domainname/AppFeatures.aspx?requestTypeSetId=30b5ae5a-551a-43d2-a215-b8b25b5aa627",
             "Slug":"Primary-Category-Admin Alphabetical-C",
             "Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
             "TypeName":"RequestTypeSet",
             "TypeId":"{30b5ae5a-551a-43d2-a215-b8b25b5aa627}",
             "Categories":[  
                {  
                   "TermSetId":"c00f1ae9-1fa3-4d39-92e1-3cf2bfe117f9",
                   "TermSetName":"Primary Category",
                   "TermName":"Admin",
                   "TermInternalName":null,
                   "TermIconRef":null
                }
             ],
             "PrimaryCategoryTerm":"Admin",
             "SecondaryCategoryTerm":"",
             "Installed":false,
             "IsNew":false,
             "IsFeatured":false,
             "IsPrivate":false,
             "RequiresApproval":false,
             "CreateUrl":"https://domainname/requestwizard.aspx?requestTypeId=ebd58ee6-cadb-4018-9987-7de2464a4bf1",
             "BuildLogUrl":null,
             "Owner":null,
             "IsOwner":false,
             "ScreenshotUrl":null,
             "Verbs":[  

             ]
          },
          {  
             "Id":"RequestTypeSet_{cc3f5b79-8ba0-4209-879f-e3eac23682cc}",
             "Title":"New Building Maintenance Issue process",
             "Description":"Manage a process to log requests for building maintenance",
             "LongDescription":"",
             "Url":"",
             "PictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=78b0c895-9a85-4911-be80-e351a5ead2e1",
             "InstancePictureUrl":"https://domainname/Json/GetAssetAsJPEG.ashx?AssetId=45923135-1ed5-48bb-bd98-9a0e8d29dd6c",
             "AddUrl":"https://domainname/default.aspx?requestTypeSetId=cc3f5b79-8ba0-4209-879f-e3eac23682cc&action=add",
             "DetailsUrl":"https://domainname/AppFeatures.aspx?requestTypeSetId=cc3f5b79-8ba0-4209-879f-e3eac23682cc",
             "Slug":"Primary-Category-Admin Alphabetical-N",
             "Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
             "TypeName":"RequestTypeSet",
             "TypeId":"{cc3f5b79-8ba0-4209-879f-e3eac23682cc}",
             "Categories":[  
                {  
                   "TermSetId":"c00f1ae9-1fa3-4d39-92e1-3cf2bfe117f9",
                   "TermSetName":"Primary Category",
                   "TermName":"Admin",
                   "TermInternalName":null,
                   "TermIconRef":null
                }
             ],
             "PrimaryCategoryTerm":"Admin",
             "SecondaryCategoryTerm":"",
             "Installed":false,
             "IsNew":false,
             "IsFeatured":false,
             "IsPrivate":false,
             "RequiresApproval":false,
             "CreateUrl":"https://domainname/requestwizard.aspx?requestTypeId=4a6befbf-8943-4ac1-9054-1903c6a44d67",
             "BuildLogUrl":null,
             "Owner":null,
             "IsOwner":false,
             "ScreenshotUrl":null,
             "Verbs":[  

             ]
          }
       ]
    }
```

What i don't know is how i can loop through each of these seemingly named objects and display them grouped on the page using Handlebars... The anticipated result should be something like this

MARKETING -------------------

Title A
Title B
Title C

HR ---------------------------

Title D
Title E

etc....

now regardless of the HTML that actually gets outputted i cannot figure out how to loop through these especially as the category names are variable.  Ive tried using loops like this..

```
"{{#each object}}",
    "{{@key}} : {{this}}",
"{{/each}}",
"{{#each array}}",
    "{{@index}} | {{this}}",
"{{/each}}",
```

Can someone suggest some alternatives?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`each-in` helper to iterate object, and inside you can use `each` helper to iterate array.

```
{{#each-in jsondata as |categoryName records|}}
 {{categoryName}}-----
 {{#each records as |item|}}
   {{item.title}}
 {{/each}}
{{/each-in}}
```

If you know exact `categoryName`, instead of iterating all the categories through `each-in` helper, you can directly get it and iterate it using `each` helper.

```
 {{#each jsondata.marketing as |item|}}
      {{item.title}}
    {{/each}}
```

if your categoryName is stored in variable then you can [`get` helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_get) to dynamically get the properties of an object

```
{{#each (get jsondata variableName) as |item|}}
    {{item.title}}
 {{/each}}
```